# YouTube Live: Record screen

Tags: java, c++, youtube, youtube-api, live-streaming

I am currently looking to develop using YouTube Live API, I was wondering if there is anyway to do a screen capture live stream.  Where the audience would see a persons screen and not the persons webcam. Similar to that of Google hangout where a person screen can be shared but using Youtube's API.

Please let me know if something of this sort is possible, I'd love to hear any feedback or suggestions.

~Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure you won't find anything like that in the YouTube API at present.  I used the API myself for a while, and it seems mostly useful for doing things like uploading videos, updating metadata, managing playlists, things like that.

Doing a live screen-capture on YouTube would require first that your YouTube account has been enabled for livestreaming.  I obtained this feature through the network I'm with, but otherwise I'm not sure how you can get it.  After that, you'd need to find some livestreaming software such as XSplit.  I use XSplit myself, but there are other programs such as Flash Media Live Encoder and OBS (Open Broadcaster Software... which is actually very good, and free).

Also, you can actually stream from Google Hangout to YouTube, without getting regular livestreaming enabled on your account.  However, I'm not entirely certain that the Google Hangout software does screen captures.  I used it once or twice but it didn't work for what I needed (gaming vids).

Comment: Hello thank you for replying!  Your feedback is appreciated. YouTube does run a live stream service that can be found at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/  Although I would like to use Youtubes Encoder Ill check out XSplit and see if that can be used for my application.  Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help.  Looks like you're new on StackOverflow, so don't forget to mark an answer, it establishes reputation ;)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know there was a livestreaming API.  Interesting :)

Comment: Yeah I was stunned too, so I wanted to see how I could make the use of it.  Also thanks for welcoming me to StackOverflow!